# How to draw poly line in google map -- android

Tags: android, android-mapview, google-maps-android-api-2

I am new to google map version 2. I used to draw a line in given LatLng. I can able to draw those line. Is there any way to draw line for specific time line. For example, i have list of latLng, i want to draw a poly line for every 3 sec. for this i used Thread.sleep(2000). But when i am doing this, my device got struck, after the all itterate done i can see the line drawing in given latLng. Is there any other way to draw line in specific time line. Thanks in advance

```
    PolylineOptions polylineOptionsPlay =   new PolylineOptions();
          for (int i = 0; i < listPoint.size(); i++) {
                try {
                    System.out.println(i);
                    LatLng drawpoly = listPoint.get(i);
                    Log.v(TAG, "Hello :: "+drawpoly);
                    polylineOptionsPlay.add(drawpoly);
                    //googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(locLatLng));
                    polyline = googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptionsPlay);
                    polyline.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    polyline.setWidth(2);

                    Thread.sleep(2000);

                } //System.out.println(stem[0]);
                catch (InterruptedException ex) {

                }
```

Comment: did you try the below?

Comment: Ya, i am trying this. i will do update once i done for sure. Thanks

Comment: let me know the results and remember not to block the ui thread. check the link in the answer.

Comment: Hi thanks, this is working fine. But the thing is i want to give time limit for one particular latlng to another. I have set of LatLng list in my DB(it has more than 10 LatLng). So when i start the loop, it should give timeline(2 sec) to draw one LatLng to another. :( I am new to this topic

Comment: you can use the below and modify the same. what is the difficulty you are facing?

Comment: you should also include these details in the question. To the question asked i have answered. You never mentioned list of 10 latlong in db.

Comment: Raghunandan, i mentioned like  "i have list of latLng". When using this handler, it draw to all point in one stretch. I am new to this topic. can you pls guide me on this

Comment: no it does not. it draws polyline by delay of 3seconds. it draws a polyline between source and destination with a delay of 3 seconds.

Comment: Okay. I have small doubt. in onMylocationChange method, i can draw poly line when the location is changes. i about to use same in this. Is there any alternative way to do this stuff.

Comment: i don't understand you comment completely.

Comment: is there any alternative way to draw like this. ? I very much new to this topic. I'm sorry if i made anything wrong

Comment: no i am not aware of an alternative sorry.

Comment: okay thanks Raghunandan :)

Answer (score 0):

If you implement Thread or HandlerThread, be sure that your UI thread does not block while waiting for the worker thread to complete—`do not call Thread.wait() or Thread.sleep()`.

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

You should not call Thread.sleep() which will block the ui thread. Instead you can use a `Handler`.

Considetring `listPoint` has list of latitudes and longitudes you can do as below

Declare the below as class variables.

```
Handler m_handler;
Runnable m_handlerTask ;
int t=0;
```

Use a `Handler` to with a delay of 3 seconds to draw polylines using lat and long

```
m_handler = new Handler();
m_handlerTask = new Runnable()
{
@Override 
public void run() { 
if(t<listPoint.size()-1)
{     
LatLng src = listPoint.get(t);
LatLng dest = listPoint.get(t + 1);
Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
    .add(new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude),
    new LatLng(dest.latitude,dest.longitude))                                       
    .width(2).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true)); 
    t++;
    }
    else
    {
   m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_handlerTask);
    } 
   m_handler.postDelayed(m_handlerTask, 3000);    
    }
};
m_handlerTask.run();
```